# 3 commander-in-chiefs of india can ever meet in one place

Tags: india

Can the army, navy and air force commander-in-chiefs meet at the same place in India ? If such a rule exists, what could be the historical reasons for the rule?

Comment: Where did you hear this?

Comment: a friend of mine was explaining this . . want to check the authenticity !

Comment: The claim, as currently presented, seems patently false becaue there's various reports of them meeting, e.g. http://www.newindianexpress.com/nation/Jaitley-to-Meet-Three-Service-Chiefs/2014/08/26/article2399334.ece

Comment: Either way, it's not History: either Skeptics or Politics.

Comment: (of course, unless it meant to ask if it was ever so)

Comment: I thought the question was meant to ask if there were historical reasons for it.

Comment: @Rajib but since no such rule exists, it would have made no sense anyway.

Comment: This **MIGHT** be on topic for [Worldbuilding.SE](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

This is a very [clear indication](http://www.ndtv.com/india-news/defence-minister-antony-meets-service-chiefs-wants-acquisitions-streamlined-474436) that they do meet:

> Then in the afternoon, he chaired the defence acquisition council
>   meeting with all three chiefs - General Singh, Air Chief Marshal NAK
>   Browne and Admiral Nirmal Verma - and the heads of the Defence
>   Research and Development Organisation (DRDO) and the Coast Guard, the
>   Defence Secretary and Defence Production Secretary present.